# MKPointAnnotation leaks memory in title

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

> ```
> MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
> pa.coordinate = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
> pa.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"place name"];//memory leaks here
> [mapView addAnnotation:pa];
> [pa release];
> ```

While running code using profiler I found that memory is leaking at tiitle, any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Why you're using `MKPointAnnotation` instead `MKAnnotation`?as far as i know [MKPointAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't have a `title` property.

Comment: MKPointAnnotation inherits from MKShape class which has title property.

Comment: simulator does not give better info about leaks. Use device to test

Comment: there doesnt seem to be any prob in this code. PS: why are u using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"place name"]; instead of just  @"place name"; since u didnt mention any format, its a plain string.

Comment: I have this problem with one project only, in 2 others this code works well. So strange...